# Bayesian Confidence Interval Estimate of Theta

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, parameter-estimation, confidence-interval

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a Bernoulli distribution with success probability $p=\theta$.  Assume a prior distribution on theta; $\theta\sim UNIFORM(0, 1)$.  Derive a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ Bayesian interval estimate of $\theta$.

Finding the Bayes estimator itself is not hard; after you do the calculation, you'll find that it's just simply the expected value of a $BETA(1+\sum x_i, 1 + n - \sum x_i)$ distribution, which is just $\frac{1+\sum x_i}{2+n}$.

My issue is just figuring out how to get the confidence interval from this information; I don't understand exactly how to do this, and the wording seems unclear to me.  Can somebody please show me what I need to do to find the interval in question?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood is
$$
L(t) = \text{constant} \times t^x (1-t)^{n-x}
$$
where $x$ is the observed sum of the Bernoulli random variables. The prior probability measure is $dt$ for $0<t<1.$ Thus the posterior is
$$
\text{constant} \times t^x(1-t)^{n-x} \, dt \quad \text{for } 0<t<1 
$$
where this "constant" may be (and in this case is) different from the other one. So this is $\operatorname{Beta}(x+1, n-x+1).$ The measure is
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(x+1) \Gamma(n-x+1)} t^x (1-t)^{n-x} \, dt = \frac{(n+1)!}{x!(n-x)!} t^x (1-t)^{n-x} \, dt \quad \text{for } 0<t<1.
$$

Suppose you want probability $1-\alpha/2$ in each tail. You need
$$
\int_0^c \frac{(n+1)!}{x!(n-x)!} t^x(1-t)^{n-x} \, dt = \frac \alpha 2.
$$
Note that

- This is a polynomial function of $c.$
- Therefore you may need numerical methods to find the value of $c,$ given $\alpha.$
- But standard software packages will give you values of the inverse of the c.d.f. of the Beta distribution.

And of course you also have
$$
\int_d^1 \frac{(n+1)!}{x!(n-x)!} t^x(1-t)^{n-x} \, dt = \frac \alpha 2
$$
and you similarly seek $d.$

Comment: To make sure that I'm understanding, without getting into the integrals, essentially the confidence interval that I'm looking for is described by the following:
$$P(INVBETACDF(\alpha/2; 1+\sum X_i, 1+n-\sum X_i\le \theta \le INVBETACDF(1-\alpha/2; 1+\sum X_i, 1+n-\sum X_i))=1-\alpha$$

In which case the confidence interval bounds are the same as those inside the probability above.  Those two parameters after the semicolon just represent the alpha and beta of that particular Beta distribution, while the first argument before the semicolon is the percentile.

Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the parenthesis before the first inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, assume you have prior $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1) \equiv \mathsf{Beta}(1,1)$ as prior, and data are 20 successes in 50 trials. Then as you say the posterior dixtribution is $\mathsf{Beta}(1+20, 1+30) = \mathsf{Beta}(21, 31)$ with point estimate $21/52.$ Using R or similar software you can find a 95% Bayesian probability interval estimate $(0.276, 0.539).$  [In R, the beta quantile function (or inverse CDF) is denoted `qbeta` with appropriate parameters.]

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 21, 31)
[1] 0.275843 0.538859
```

This is a specific computed instance of @MichaelHardy's Answer (+1).

*Note:* This interval estimate is numerically similar to the Agresti-Coull interval
using $n^+ = n + 4$ and $\tilde p = (X+2)/n^+.$ The interval is
$$\tilde p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\tilde p(1-\tilde p)}{n^+}}.$$
For the example above, it computes to $(0.2763530, 0.5384619).$ [Of course,
numerical similarity aside,
the *interpretations* if the Bayesian and frequentist intervals differ.]