# Is choosing confidence interval bounds after observing data mathematically valid?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

Let $D$ be a continuous distribution on the interval $[0,1]$ that is not known to us. We have no prior knowledge about $D$. For a given error tolerance $\delta$ we want to find bounds $a, b$ s.t. $b-a$ is minimized while for a random variable $X \sim D$ we have $Pr(a\leq X\leq b)\geq 1-\delta$.

To do this we sample $X_i \sim D$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and view it as a Bernoulli trial where a successs is characterized by $X_i$ being within the bounds. By $k$ we denote the number of successes, i.e., $k=\lvert\{X_i \mid a\leq X_i \leq b \}\rvert$. Then, for $X \sim D$ and $f$ being the pdf of $D$ we can say

$$Pr(a \leq X \leq b) = I_b(k+1,n-k+1) - I_a(k+1,n-k+1)$$

where $I_x$ is the regularized, incomplete Beta function.

---

Now I understand that this procedure works fine when working out $Pr(a \leq X \leq b)$ given $a,b$ and all $X_i$.

My question is whether it is valid to apply the reverse here, i.e., given a bound for $Pr(a \leq X \leq b)$ and all $X_i$, can we find bounds $a$ and $b$?

A similar question can be found [for example in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704347/bayesian-confidence-interval-estimate-of-theta), but in my case specifically the difference is that adapting $a$ and $b$ directly affects the success probability of the Bernoulli trial.

Is it still valid to simply choose/find $a$ and $b$ s.t. $Pr(a\leq X \leq b) \geq 1-\delta$ is fulfilled, or do I need to formulate a new hypothesis and collect new data every time I change $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Ignoring the trivial $a=0,b=1$, your finite sample will never ensure $\Pr(a\leq X \leq b) \geq 1-\delta$ since you may be unlucky with your sample,  but if you say you want this to happen at least with probability $1-\epsilon$ and your sample is large enough, you can find non-trivial $a$ and $b$ as functions of the order statistics of the sample

Comment: Can't you just take $a = 0$ and $b = 1.$ Then $P(a \leq X \leq b) = 1.$ Otherwise, what are you asking of $a$ and $b$? If you have a generous amount of samples, you can plot a histogram of the values and get an idea of the shape of $D.$ You can then do a first approximation of $D$ and then estimating its parameters (another approximation) and finally finding a confidence interval, of course, all of this are approximations. In a real-life setting, this is more or less what one would do.

Comment: @Henry So if we choose a $\delta'$ and formulate the hypothesis $Pr(a\leq X\leq b) \geq 1-\delta'$, we can calculate the probability of the hypothesis being true from the data as $1-\epsilon$? Then the total error probability is bounded by $1-(1-\epsilon)(1-\delta')$, i.e., we consider the probability that the hypothesis is correct and that $Pr(a\leq X\leq b)$ under the hypothesis, correct? Of course finding a suitable $\delta'$ then is another task.

Comment: @WilliamM. The point is to give tight bounds $a,b$. This does not necessarily mean to minimize $b-a$ but to make it reasonably small. I'll add that in the question.

Comment: Consider $\frac{1}{n} \sum U_i,$ where the $U_i$ are uniform $[0, 1].$ This sum is highly concentrated around $\frac{1}{2}$ so $a$ and $b$ can be quite close to $\frac{1}{2}.$ Now consider something with density proportional to $|x-\frac{1}{2}|^d.$ This density has almost no weight around $\frac{1}{2}$ and depending on $d,$ $a$ and $b$ will both be close to $1.$ Suppose now that $D$ is the uniform distribution. Then $0 < a < b < 1$ with $b-a = 1-\delta$ will work, regardless of how asymetric around $\frac{1}{2}$ they are.  What sense of tightness are you using?

Comment: Tight in the sense that $b-a$ is small. I guess the task can be viewed as "minimize $b-a$ under the constraint that $Pr(a \leq b) \geq 1-\delta$, given the data"

Comment: @PattuX - I think combining two types of probabilities in that way is likely to lead to confusion, except in a Bayesian setting.  Suppose you had a sample sized $1000$ and you then announced $\Pr\left(X_{(25)}\leq X\leq X_{(976)}\right) \ge 0.95$ in your formulation.  Would that be understood to mean that at least $95\%$ of future samples from that particular distribution would be between the particular observed $x_{(25)}$ and $x_{(976)}$? That would be a misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of major problems that invalidate your approach: (1) It makes very unreasonable assumptions about the prior distribution for the unknown $p:=P(a < X < b)$, and (2) It confuses the posterior distribution of this quantity with the quantity itself, leading to nonsensical results (such as the equation you wrote involving the Beta c.d.f.).

As the problem is formulated, there are $n$ Bernoulli trials -- call them $Y_1,..,Y_n,$ where $Y_i=1_{a<X_i<b},$ for i.i.d. $X_1,..,X_n\sim D$ -- and the number of "successes" is $K:=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i.$ The Beta-Binomial model is then
$$\begin{align}(K\mid p)&\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)\tag{1}\\
p&\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)\tag{2}\\
\\
(p\mid K=k)&\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha+k,\beta+n-k)\tag{3}
\end{align}$$
where
$$p:=P(a<X<b),\quad X\sim D.$$

1. You've assumed a fixed prior ($\alpha=\beta=1$) for $p:=P(a<X<b)$ *irrespective* of $a$ and $b$ -- which seems not at all reasonable.
2. For given constants $A,B$ (*unrelated* to $a,b$), the posterior (3) implies
   $$P(A<p<B\mid K=k)=I_B(1+k,1+n-k)-I_A(1+k,1+n-k).$$
   In particular, the model **does not imply** this equation:
   $$P(a<X<b\mid K=k)=I_b(1+k,1+n-k)-I_a(1+k,1+n-k).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you clarify what you mean by "not at all reasonable" in (1.)? Would it be reasonable if $a$ and $b$ were given as constants?

Comment: @PattuX We can imagine this "unknown probability" $p:=P(a<X<b)$ as the almost-sure long-run limit of a proportion in an i.i.d. sample. Then, roughly speaking, if $a\approx b$ (resp. $a<<1/2<<b$), then a prior pdf $f(p)$ should concentrate the probability-mass near $p=0$ (resp. $p=1$), with other shapes in intermediate cases. The point is that this depends on $a,b.$  On the other hand, if $a,b$ were fixed once and for all, then objection (1) wouldn't apply -- except to say that the choice $\alpha=\beta=1,$ i.e. $f(p)=1[0\le p\le 1]$ (uniform), may or may not be appropriate, as just described.